# Querying Mediastore for a file created outside the App returns nothing

Tags: java, android, mediastore, android-11

Querying MediaStore.Downloads for a file uploaded throught the Device Explorer (and thus created outside the App) returns nothing.

If the file is rather created via the .insert method by the App the same query returns the file as expected.

Is this some kind of permission issue there?

File location is = \Download\MyApp\MyFile.csv

```
        String selection = MediaStore.Downloads.RELATIVE_PATH + " LIKE ? ";
        // appfoldername = "MyApp"
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                '%' + Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + File.separator + appfoldername + '%'
                 };

        Cursor cursor  = resolver.query(MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] {MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE}, selection, selectionArgs, null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#request-permissions):

> If your app wants to access a file within the `MediaStore.Downloads` collection that your app didn't create, you must use the Storage Access Framework. To learn more about how to use this framework, see the guide on how to access documents and other files.

Comment: OK, that would explain why I'm getting a "EACCES (permission denied)" error.